# Why isn't my post JSON object getting serialized?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Why isn't my POST JSON object getting serialized? I'm using Web API 2.0. My controller route looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddUserAsync([FromBody] User user)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

My `User` object looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I pass the following JSON object the Id and Name props get serialized with null values:

```
{
    "Id": "895C4492-B751-462C-9738-C6CB4E94E21F",
    "Name": "Joe System"
}
```

Do I need to decorate `User` with `[DataContract]` or something like that?

How to manage this in Web API 2?

Comment: Your properties are not public. You need to make them public ie `public  Guid Id { get; set; }`

Comment: If the answer provided resolves your issue you are suppose to [mark it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so that the question can be considered completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your properties are not public. You need to make them public

```
public class User {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The model binder inspects the intended object type and populates public properties.

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)